# How to create records in CRM using liquid script in portal without entity form

Tags: liquid, dynamics-crm-portals

How to create records in CRM using liquid script in portal without entity form.
Ex. I have a submit button. When I click on that I'm getting some id's using that id's I need to create records in crm. Anyone know pls help me.